# mysql user variable within an IN where statement

Tags: mysql, select, user-defined

I now gave up and sorted it by other means but because "curiosity killed the cat" I am trying to figure out how to use mysql query @variables within an IN where statement:

So, from this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID IN (794,758)
```

Try to include a variable and this returns a syntax error:

```
SET @variousids="(794,758)";
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID IN @variousids
```

This returns values only from the first:

```
SET @variousids="794,758";
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID IN (@variousids)
```

I've tried different syntax, values and have not found any specific doc about defining list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :-

```
SET @variousids="794,758";
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID FIND_IN_SET (table1.ID,@variousids)
```

Comment: Thanks, was just about to write about that was the solution I found.

Comment: This one gives me an error, while the one in the other answer works... The 'table1.ID` right after the where cannot be used in MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 8):

Use `find_in_set` . The below will work.

```
SET @variousids="794,758";
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE find_in_set(table1.ID,@variousids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
SET @variousids="794,758";
prepare stmt from 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.ID IN ( ? )'
execute stmt using @variousids;
```

For more info, check [THIS](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html) article.